USDC on Solana not able to trade to other coins for a couple weeks
I have USDC in my wallet but everytime I've tried to trade it for another coin the past couple weeks it says i have insufficient balance. I have Solana and USDC in my wallet, so I know i do have sufficient balance. Is USDC on Solana not working for everybody or is it just me?
